# CSS Expanding/sliding text animation

Tags: css, animation, expand

I can't quite describe this good enough so I made this [gif](https://gfycat.com/LimpingFriendlyAntarcticfurseal).
I would like for those links/text to slide out of one word when I hover or click.
Can someone help me create something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```css
#one, #two {
  float:left;
  color:#ffffff;
  width:130px;
}
#one {
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:0.3em;
  background-color:#000000;
}
#two {
  position:relative;
  left:-130px;
  z-index:-10;
  transition:left 0.5s;
}
body {
  background-color:#000000;
}
body:hover #two {
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">Social</div>
<div id="two">| Twitter | Facebook</div>
```

### How it Works

Both `#one` (the div containing "Social") and `#two` are floated left, so they appear side-by-side, rather than underneath each other. The are also set to be both `130px` wide, and to have a white text colour.

`#one` is set to have a black background, so that nothing underneath it is seen. `#two` is then positioned to be `-130px` pixels left of where it would have been, i.e. directly underneath `#one`, and it's `z-index` is set to be negative, so it appears below `#two`. We also set the `transition` property, so that when the `left` style is changed, it is animated.

And, that's all the setup. To make things look better, I set the `background-color` to black on `body`, and as a demo made `#two`'s `left` style be set to `0` whenever you hover over the `body` - really though you could do this anywhere - when `#one` is hovered over, etc, or even using Javascript.